# spring.resources.chain.strategy.content.enabled only working on .css files

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to enable ContentVersionStrategy for JavaScript and CSS files within a Spring Boot application using Thymeleaf as the view engine.

In a [sample project](https://github.com/moose56/stackoverflow-cache-busting) I have added the following to the application properties file:

```
# add classpath:/custom/ as a possible location
spring.resources.static-locations=classpath:/META-INF/resources/,classpath:/resources/,classpath:/static/,classpath:/public/,classpath:/custom/

# enable ContentVersionStrategy
spring.resources.chain.strategy.content.enabled=true
spring.resources.chain.strategy.content.paths=/**
```

This works for .css files in the application but not .js files. From what I can read it should also work on .js files.

I have also tried to do this manually rather than just in the properties file with:

```java
@Configuration
public class WebConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer
{
    private static final String[] CLASSPATH_RESOURCE_LOCATIONS = {
            "classpath:/META-INF/resources/", "classpath:/resources/",
            "classpath:/static/", "classpath:/public/", "classpath:/custom/"};

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry)
    {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/**").addResourceLocations(CLASSPATH_RESOURCE_LOCATIONS)
                .resourceChain(true)
                .addResolver(new VersionResourceResolver().addContentVersionStrategy("/**"));
    }
}
```

But this does not work for .css files or .js.

I have tried with with Spring Boot 2.1.4.RELEASE, 2.2.0.M2, 2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT, Java 11 and 12 just in case there were any differences.

Any reason my the property file method does not seem to apply to .js files?

Is there anything obviously wrong with my `WebMvcConfigurer` implementation that means it does not apply to either .css or .js?

Answer (score 2):

So after 5 hours of digging through Spring to try and work out why the content hash values for javascript files were not being generated I spotted the difference between the css and js links:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title>Test page</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/css/jquery-ui.min.css}"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/directory/select2.min.css}"/>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Text page</p>
    <script th:src="@{js/jquery.js}"></script>
    <script th:src="@{js/select2.min.js}"></script>
    <script th:src="@{directory/jquery-ui.min.js}"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

the script tags are missing the forward slash at the start. Adding it fixes the issue.

Also found the bit I was missing to do it manually:

```java
@Configuration
public class WebConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer
{
    private static final String[] CLASSPATH_RESOURCE_LOCATIONS = {
            "classpath:/META-INF/resources/", "classpath:/resources/",
            "classpath:/static/", "classpath:/public/", "classpath:/custom/"};

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry)
    {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/**").addResourceLocations(CLASSPATH_RESOURCE_LOCATIONS)
                .resourceChain(true)
                .addResolver(new VersionResourceResolver().addContentVersionStrategy("/**"));
    }

    @Bean
    public ResourceUrlEncodingFilter resourceUrlEncodingFilter() {
        return new ResourceUrlEncodingFilter();
    }
}
```

I needed to add the `ResourceUrlEncodingFilter` bean.

Comment: To be clear to future readers, there is no need to the manual steps, just adding `spring.resources.chain.strategy.content.enabled=true
spring.resources.chain.strategy.content.paths=/**` to your `application.properties` works (Tested with Spring Boot 2.2.6)